# Laravel accessing BelongsTo Model of a HasMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Basically I have three models , Wedding , invites , and users. Weddings has invites and invites has users **( keeping in mind that user can belong to multiple invites )**. I want to access `$wedding->users` directly.

**Wedding.php**

```
class Wedding extends Model
{

  public function invites()
  {
     return $this->hasMany(Invite::class);
  }
...
```

**Invites.php**

```
class Invite extends Model
{

  public function user()
  {
     return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }
...
```

Tables:

```
Wedding
- id
- name

Invite
- invite_date
- wedding_id
- user_id

User
- id
- name
- email
```

And i want to access retrieve users directly , using `$wedding->users`
What's the relationship between Wedding and users?

Comment: [Has many through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through), its all in the documentation.

Comment: @Kyslik it's not HasManyThrough because User does not contain invite_id

Comment: You can change primary / foreign keys just see the signature of `hasManyThrough` definition, `belongsToMany` is also *valid*, while it uses pivot table `invites` as mentioned by Jonas. The difference is just semantic, you read it like "wedding has many users through invites" instead of "wedding belongs to users".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [`BelongsToMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship:

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'invites');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to your Widding class

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User', 'App\Invite');
}
```

for more about `hasManyThrough` see the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through).

Comment: It's not because user column does not contain invite_id